# chown failed during docker container start up, when trying to change a config file mounted from host

Tags: docker, volume, chown

I have a simple question regarding to docker. I am trying to run a openmicroscopy/apacheds container in a linux host using root. I have my own config.ldif file, and mapping into the container's original config.ldif during the start up according to the instruction. But  I failed to run the container, when I check the log, the start up script tried to change the owner of the config.ldif to apacheds:apacheds, this is a user only exist in the container. From my knowledge, when I run the container, if I never specify a user, it will be using root in the container, which means the root in the container try to change owner of config.ldif, but failed. By the way, in the host, the config.ldif belongs to root:root. I am very confused. I have tried -u root, or priviledged = true, both not work as well. According to my knowledge, this change owner command should run, inside the container, the file should belong to apacheds:apacheds, and if the apacheds user in the container has userid 999 for example, the file in the outside host should belong to 999:999? Please help me if possible, thanks a lot.

Comment: The container will run by default as the user configured in the image; it's possible for a container to start as root and then switch to an unprivileged user.  A [mcve] showing how you built the image, the exact `docker run` command you're using, and the error you're getting would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks David, I have added some more information about this. @DavidM

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks David, I have added some more information about the docker file and run.sh, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    The docker file is: 
    
    FROM ubuntu:16.04
    MAINTAINER ome-devel@lists.openmicroscopy.org.uk
    
    #############################################
    # ApacheDS installation
    #############################################
    
    ENV APACHEDS_VERSION 2.0.0.AM26
    ENV APACHEDS_ARCH amd64
    
    ENV APACHEDS_ARCHIVE apacheds-${APACHEDS_VERSION}-${APACHEDS_ARCH}.deb
    ENV APACHEDS_DATA /var/lib/apacheds
    ENV APACHEDS_USER apacheds
    ENV APACHEDS_GROUP apacheds
    
    RUN ln -s ${APACHEDS_DATA}-${APACHEDS_VERSION} ${APACHEDS_DATA}
    VOLUME ${APACHEDS_DATA}
    
    RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y \
           apt-utils
    
    RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections \
        && apt-get install -y \
           ldap-utils \
           procps \
           openjdk-8-jre-headless \
           curl \
           jq \
        && curl https://downloads.apache.org/directory/apacheds/dist/${APACHEDS_VERSION}/${APACHEDS_ARCHIVE} > ${APACHEDS_ARCHIVE} \
        && dpkg -i ${APACHEDS_ARCHIVE} \
        && rm ${APACHEDS_ARCHIVE}
    
    # Ports defined by the default instance configuration:
    # 10389: ldap
    # 10636: ldaps
    # 60088: kerberos
    # 60464: changePasswordServer
    # 8080: http
    # 8443: https
    EXPOSE 10389 10636 60088 60464 8080 8443
    
    #############################################
    # ApacheDS bootstrap configuration
    #############################################
    
    ENV APACHEDS_INSTANCE default
    ENV APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP /bootstrap
    
    ADD scripts/run.sh /run.sh
    RUN chown ${APACHEDS_USER}:${APACHEDS_GROUP} /run.sh \
        && chmod u+rx /run.sh
    
    ADD instance/* ${APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP}/conf/
    RUN sed -i "s/ads-contextentry:: [A-Za-z0-9\+\=\/]*/ads-contextentry:: $(base64 -w 0 $APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP/conf/ads-contextentry.decoded)/g" /$APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP/conf/config.ldif
    ADD ome.ldif ${APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP}/
    RUN mkdir ${APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP}/cache \
        && mkdir ${APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP}/run \
        && mkdir ${APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP}/log \
        && mkdir ${APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP}/partitions \
        && chown -R ${APACHEDS_USER}:${APACHEDS_GROUP} ${APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP}
    
    RUN apt-get install -y python-ldap
    ADD bin/ldapmanager /usr/local/bin/ldapmanager
    
    #############################################
    # ApacheDS wrapper command
    #############################################
    
    # Correct for hard-coded INSTANCES_DIRECTORY variable
    RUN sed -i "s#/var/lib/apacheds-${APACHEDS_VERSION}#/var/lib/apacheds#" /opt/apacheds-${APACHEDS_VERSION}/bin/apacheds
    
    
    RUN curl -L -o /usr/local/bin/dumb-init \
        https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.1/dumb-init_1.2.1_amd64 && \
        chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
    
    ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
    =============================================================

The run.sh is below: 

#!/usr/local/bin/dumb-init /bin/bash

# Environment variables:
# APACHEDS_VERSION
# APACHEDS_INSTANCE
# APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP
# APACHEDS_DATA
# APACHEDS_USER
# APACHEDS_GROUP

APACHEDS_INSTANCE_DIRECTORY=${APACHEDS_DATA}/${APACHEDS_INSTANCE}
PIDFILE="${APACHEDS_INSTANCE_DIRECTORY}/run/apacheds-${APACHEDS_INSTANCE}.pid"

# When a fresh data folder is detected then bootstrap the instance configuration.
if [ ! -d ${APACHEDS_INSTANCE_DIRECTORY} ]; then
    mkdir ${APACHEDS_INSTANCE_DIRECTORY}
    cp -rv ${APACHEDS_BOOTSTRAP}/* ${APACHEDS_INSTANCE_DIRECTORY}
    chown -v -R ${APACHEDS_USER}:${APACHEDS_GROUP} ${APACHEDS_INSTANCE_DIRECTORY}
fi

cleanup(){
    if [ -e "${PIDFILE}" ];
    then
        echo "Cleaning up ${PIDFILE}"
        rm "${PIDFILE}"
    fi
}

trap cleanup EXIT
cleanup

/opt/apacheds-${APACHEDS_VERSION}/bin/apacheds start ${APACHEDS_INSTANCE}
sleep 2  # Wait on new pid

shutdown(){
    echo "Shutting down..."
    /opt/apacheds-${APACHEDS_VERSION}/bin/apacheds stop ${APACHEDS_INSTANCE}
}

trap shutdown INT TERM
tail -n 0 --pid=$(cat $PIDFILE) -f ${APACHEDS_INSTANCE_DIRECTORY}/log/apacheds.log

    ==============================================================================
    
        After running this docker image, the {config.ldif} file owner and group in the container become ?. I am not sure why is that. And I also didn't find where is the place in either docker file, or run.sh script to run the apacheds as apacheds? Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

One more update here, I have found some problem in my config.ldif file and corrected it. When I tried to rerun the container, it works,

docker run --name ldap -d -p 389:10389 -e APACHEDS_INSTANCE=yourinstance -v /path/to/your/config.ldif:/bootstrap/conf/config.ldif:ro openmicroscopy/apacheds

however, when I login to the container, and see the config.ldif in /bootstrap/conf/ directory, the owner group of this file is root:root, while the rest of the files are apacheds:apacheds, why the config.ldif is not changed to apacheds:apachds? Thanks.